# IBM API Connect - Security Set up Issue - API Key in the Header not working

Tags: apiconnect

We are working on hosting a REST API in APIC.

I am able to test the API using APIC endpoint by turning off the security. But when I enabled the security (using API Key) I am facing problem. In fact, I am able to pass the api key in the query and able to run GET operations successfully.

However, we really want to pass the API key (X-IBM-Client-Id) in the header for Authorization. when I pass the API key in the header, I get **500 Internal Server**

> Error (Headers:
>   content-type: text/xml; charset="utf-8" x-backside-transport: FAIL FAIL). *Any idea why I am not able to pass the client ID in the header successfully? *

Answer (score 0):

When you are on the *API Security Definition* page, and the *Type* entry is *API key*, there is a drop-down list with a choice of 'Header' or 'Query'.

My guess is that you have chosen 'Query'. Change it to 'Header' and you should be OK.

Comment: @AnupGupta, was this solved?